# Impact of adding clustered indexes to SQL Server that is currently in use

Tags: sql, sql-server, clustered-index

I want to add a clustered index to a SQL Server table that I am currently using and have built numerous queries and code around it.

I want to be certain that adding these indexes does not affect how I make queries and updates in my code. My understanding is that it does not have any impact on the code, would that be correct?

Comment: *"So I want to be certain that adding these queries does not affect how I make queries and updates in my code."* What? You don't "add" a query to a table.

Comment: For SQL performance help, you need to provide us with table and index definitions, relevant queries, and share query plans via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Comment: @Charlieface That's not what this question is about.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen "I want to be certain that adding these indexes does not affect how I make queries and updates in my code." It certainly can make a difference. You should always try to write a query in a way that makes it easier for the compiler to hit indexes, ergo, if you change the indexes you may need to change the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding an index might affect the execution plan of a given SQL query, but it should have no effect on the logical result set.  Note that adding an index to a table, while possibly improving query performance, may hinder DML (update, insert, delete, etc.) performance.  During every DML operation, the index has to be maintained, and there is a cost to this.  Usually the biggest DML hit happens when adding the very first index to a table, with much smaller hits for subsequent indices.  Also, it is usually counterproductive to have more than 6-7 separate indices on a single table.

Comment: *"the biggest DML hit happens when adding the very first index to a table, with much smaller hits for subsequent indices."* please back that up with a source, I'm not aware of any such generalization